# How to resolve the conflict in azure environment on pull request approval

Tags: git, azure

My teams working with different location, they share their code to me in azure portal. when they give the pull request I review and approve their code and merging to master.

when i do that, once of the person's code show that merge conflict. In this case how can i solve the conflict?

not getting any idea. please help me here.
screen shot attached.

[image: conflict state]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is: you don't.

You ask that person to fetch from your Azure repo, and rebase his/her PR (Pull Request) branch on top of that fetched repository.

That will trigger conflicts, but on their side, not yours (Azure).
They can then force push the same (rewritten) PR branch, and you can review and merge, except this time, it will be a trivial merge (no conflict). The work of resolving conflict should be delegated on the developer side, not the reviewer.